# How to display null attributes in Response entity with custom type

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

In my firm, we are using spring boot 2.1.13. Currently an API's return type is, ResponseEntity of customType. The response of the API is not returning the attributes which has null values(example, if email is null then it wont present in the response). But my client requirement is, we should sent null attributes as well irrespective of the value of the attribute. What I have tried so far is, change the response type to ResponseEntity of String and did the following code changes,

```
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myResponse);
```

This string response returns null attributes. But the problem is, this API is already used by another external system, so we cannot change the response type of this API. We are using following jackson dependency in the parent POM pom.xml

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.8</version>
                </dependency>
```

Response class is,

```
public class BusinessModel {
    protected Date activationDate;
    protected Date expiryDate;
    protected String serviceStatus;
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected String companyName;
    protected String email;
    protected String departmentName;
}
```

We are using JDK 1.8. As I am new to Java, any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [`Include.ALWAYS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#ALWAYS), either on the field as annotation or on the `ObjectMapper` as `SerializationInclusion`. See [this baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields) for reference.

Comment: tried Include.ALWAYS in the response class, but no luck.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the problem with the given information](https://github.com/turing85/jackson-serialization). Can you please share a complete [MRE] (best in form of a github repository)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a webMvcConfig class where you configure JacksonMapper?
Or else you shoud override JacksonMapper and set serialization inclusion
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);

Comment: Please use comments to ask for clarification and do not post speculative answers.

Comment: It is not speculative :-) . You should override default jackson mapper or add
spring boot property 
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=always. Just trying to help

Comment: "*Do you have a webMvcConfig class where you configure JacksonMapper?*" - It is speculative.

Comment: we dont use any config class @codiallo

Comment: Ok add spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=always.
If it does not work with that spring boot version, you should override default mapper config. Tell me if you need an example for that

Comment: spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=always not working,
tell me an example to override the mapper config @codiallo

Comment: @codiallo its working, but my date field value is modified. We are using java.util.Date for activationDate field. Previously activationDate converted to some random number like 1607949795000. Any idea why its modified?